# label for jsf generated id

Tags: html, jsf

In the attribute `for` of the element `<label>`, is there a way to make reference to a generated jsf id?

The jquery will now work there, it will generate:

```
<label for='$(this).closest(".my-input-text").attr("id")'>MyLabel</label>

<span class="generated-spam-element">
  <span class="generated-spam-element">
    <input id="jsf:long:generated:id:MyInput" class="my-input-text" />
  </span>
</span>
```

(I'm also using primefaces, if there's any solution using it)

Comment: Use https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/outputLabel.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries the `for="@next"` will not work, becouse my target input is also generated by primefaces inside two `<span>` elements... But I have the id of the input (the last part of it, "MyInput" in the example), if I could reference that id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work with `h:outputLabel` instead of `label` or `p:outputLabel`.